# What does the A in ~A in format stand for?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

With `format` you can use, among other things, `~S` and `~A`.

While the `S` in `~S` is for `S-expression`, what does the `A` in `~A` stand for? Apparently it outputs without escaping, but I was wondering what the letter actually means…?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this shows no research effort and it is answered in the *title* of the relevant documentation [22.3.4.1 Tilde A: Aesthetic](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cda.htm).

Comment: Although I'm the author of the question, I have to agree. I didn't think of the hyper spec and I didn't come up with an idea how to Google for the term. Maybe I should have thought about it a minute longer. Sorry for that :-(

Comment: It's an honest mistake, and it's much easier to see things in hindsight.  That said, it's usually a good idea to search the HyperSpec (or whatever relevant manual for the tool/language at hand), since many of these things are laid out pretty clearly.  E.g., how would someone even *know* about ~a if it weren't documented somewhere?  That doesn't necessarily mean that the documentation will explain the name, but it's really the first place to start.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It stands for Aesthetic.  `A`-formatted output is not escaped.  See http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cda.htm

Incidentally, `S` stands for Standard rather than S-expression.